# How to connect to mysql localhost on opensuse?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, opensuse

first the details of the configuration:

1. openSUSE 11.3 with Parallels Plesk Panel 10 (64-bit) Server
2. MySQL installed and running (no "skip-networking")
3. java 1.6.0_24 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode))

The mysql server listens on 0.0.0.0:3306

```
netstat -lnp | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3499/mysqld         
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10916  3499/mysqld         /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Now the problem.
I can not connect to the mysql from localhost with jdbc (mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar) using this class:

```
public class Connect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            String userName = "user";
            String password = "password";
            // This also doesn't work with "localhost" in the connect string.
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database";

            System.out.println("URL: " + url);

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            System.out.println("Database connection established");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Cannot connect to database server");
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                    System.out.println("Database connection terminated");
                } catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More details:

telnet gives time out

```
telnet localhost 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection timed out
```

nmap shows the port 3306 is filtered on localhost

```
nmap -p 3306 localhost
Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-08-30 19:21 CEST
Interesting ports on localhost (127.0.0.1):
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp filtered mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.31 seconds
```

If I connect from outside to the servers 3306 port with the Connect class, everything works fine.

As I think this is something with the firewall. This is the automatically generated firewall from the plesk configuration center.

```
iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 reject-with tcp-reset 
DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10000 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4306 
DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:12443 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:11443 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:11444 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8447 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8443 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8880 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:587 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:465 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:995 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:143 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:993 
DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:106 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:5432 
DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:5432 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:9008 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:9080 
DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:9008 
DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:9080 
DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:137 
DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:138 
DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:139 
DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:445 
DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:1194 
ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53 
DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 code 0 
DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 reject-with tcp-reset 
DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
ACCEPT     all  --  lo     lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 reject-with tcp-reset 
DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Furthermore I can connect with perl to the local mysql.

```
$dsn = "dbi:mysql:$database:localhost:3306";
$connect = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw);
```

I would be regretful for any hint to the solution of this.
Martin

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but... is your database really called "database"?

Comment: I don't do opensuse, so I may be totally wrong, but did you try `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` in your JDBC URL?

Comment: No, its not called database. I changed the arguments for publishing.

Comment: I tried localhost instead of 127.0.0.1, even for the nmap and telnet command.

Comment: Just a random comment: Could it be due to ipv6? Could explain the difference between connecting from outside(ipv4) and inside(possibly ipv6)..

Comment: To connect from outside I use the same Connect class with the servers address instead of localhost/127.0.0.1 in the connect string.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify your IPTables?  If you can, try adding this rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: There is a rule which accepts tcp on 0.0.0.0 dpt:3306. And I already inserted this extra rule.

Comment: @Martin If you nmap your localhost again does it still show port 3306 as filtered? It shouldn't if you actually inserted the above rule. It should show it as OPEN. If above doesn't work, simply flush your iptables with iptables -F and try connecting again to make sure is not iptables that's getting in the middle. But I'm like 99.999% sure that the issue is with your firewall since telnet timesout and nmap says port 3306 is filtered. Bottom line is that it shouldn't be so.

Comment: @Nate C-K: Good question. I hadn't seen that part of the question (I supposed Martin updated it). I have no idea why perl connects but if there's nothing in the middle telnet to localhost 3306 should answer.

Comment: @Icarus I already did a flush with the result, that I could not reach the server afterwards. I will investigate the possibilities of the server provider furthermore, maybe I missed something there.

Comment: Is it possible, that perl connects to the socket and jdbc doesn't?

Comment: @Martin: rcSuSEfirewall2 restart will restore the IP tables to the previous state. If that's the case with Perl, then telnet would work too since telnet opens a socket connection as well. On the contrary, Perl may connect to MySQL through a named pipe (but that only works on Windows) and that's why it may succeed; but remotely, there's no other way to connect from one computer to another unless it's via tcp/ip or udp.

Answer (score 0):

Is your user created with priviledges to access the database from localhost?
How did you create the user?

```
grant all on database.* to 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
grant all on database.* to 'user'@'%' identified by 'password';
```

Either one might do the trick. I had problems before without the hostname specified.